# Can't put this div scrollbar to the bottom

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have a `Chat` component with some methods and it has piece of code that generate messages sent by two people one below another.

```
render() {
    ...
    <div id="window" className="window">
        <div className="messages">
            {this._renderMessages()}
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
}
```

The method only generates more `div` with varying styles depending who sent the message, and `window` has a vertical `overflow` set to `auto` but it is always at the top.

```
.window {
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-height: 264px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

My attempts were to take the `window` element by its ID and set its `scrollTop` of 0 to the value of `scrollHigh`, but it isn't working. It is making no difference.

```
const window = document.getElementById("window");
window.scrollTop = window.scrollHeight;
```

I tried placing the code above in `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` but none worked. I also attempted to set a `ref` on the `div` and access it with `this.refs.window` but it did not work either, despite showing the values. What am I doing wrong when attempting to assign the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to run the scroll-to-bottom code after every update (*and on initial render*). The life-cycle methods for these actions are `componentDidMount` (*for initial render*) and `componentDidUpdate` (*for subsequent updates*).

So something like

```js
class YourComponent extends ...{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.window = React.createRef();
  }
  scrollToBottom(){
    const element = this.window.current;
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.scrollToBottom()
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  render() {
      ...
      <div id="window" className="window" ref={this.window}>
          <div className="messages">
              {this._renderMessages()}
          </div>
      </div>
      ...
  }
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/y3qvv04l7j

---

Keep in mind that you might want to do some checks before scrolling to bottom after each update, if for example you want to allow scrolling until new data are displayed etc..

Comment: It has solved my issue, but I found the element by ID instead.